# SQLITE NESTED DB Queries

Tags: sqlite

SQLITE DATABASE IS IN BELOW FORMAT:

Below TABLES are there
DataModel
File

```
_1011_105
_1011_106
_1011_107
```

and so on

and the _1011_106 (format of tables _1011) have below Columns (like ID,MODEL etc).

I did Below query search for searching all the tables in SqLiteDatabase

**`select name FROM sqlite_master where tbl_name like '%$_1011%' ESCAPE '$'`**

But I need to run one more query from the result of above query 
From above query I got all the names like

```
_1011_2
_1011_106
_1011_107
```

Hence I need to run query on these list like

**`Select * FROM (on each element of list I got from above query) WHERE MODEL='4001'`**

How this can be done in nested way?

Something like

```
select * from (select name FROM sqlite_master where tbl_name like '%$_1011%' ESCAPE '$');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite has no mechanism to create dynamic SQL.

You have to read the list of table names first, and then construct a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) like this in your program:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (SELECT * FROM _1011_105
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM _1011_106
      ...)
WHERE Model = '4001';
```